# Want to open popup in button click SPFX React

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, popup, react

I Want to show modal popup in spfx react webpart. Below is the code I am using:

```
<div>
   <button onClick={e => this._OpenModal(this)}>Open Modal</button>
   <div id="myModal" className="modal">
      <div className="modal-content">
          <span className="close" onClick={e => this._CloseModal(this)}>&times;</span>
          <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

private _OpenModal = (e): void => {
    e.style.display = "block";
    // tslint:disable-next-line:semicolon
};

private _CloseModal = (e): void => {
    e.style.display = "none";
    // tslint:disable-next-line:semicolon
};
```

But I am unable to fire `style.display`.

Please guide ne how to fire the event?

Error :

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
>       at ShopingCart._this._OpenModal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do this:

1. Add a boolean variable in your state (e.g.: `isLoaded` or `showDialog`). Let's use `showDialog`
2. In your render code, use conditional rendering to render the dialog. E.g.:

```
{this.state.showDialog && <div id="myModal" className="modal">
      <div className="modal-content">
          <span className="close" onClick={e => this._CloseModal(this)}>&times;</span>
          <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
      </div>
   </div>}
```

3. Change your `_ShowModal` and `_CloseModal` code to change the state, as follows:

```
private _OpenModal = (e): void => {
    this.setState({
       showDialog: true
    });
}

private _CloseModal = (e): void => {
    this.setState({
       showDialog: false
    });
}
```

It should work for you.